# How to determine "clock" shape connections?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a challenge to which I'm trying to devise a solution.  This might best be suited to the [math](http://math.stackexchange.com) side of things but I'm hoping there is a pre-existing library or well-known algorithm that might work.
Simply stated, I have four shapes that will be laid out in a grid and I'm trying to determine if they connect when the endpoints align.  Or put another way, think of rows of clocks.  When the hands of one clock point at the hands of another they are "connected".  To further extend the analogy I only have 4 "times": 3:00, 6:15, 5:45, 9:00 (ignore what might be a big vs little hand).
For purposes of discussion lets assume the clocks are aligned in rows so there are limited connections possible (in the final solution these clocks will be aligned in a grid).
I have attempted to apply various mathematical concepts to this including simply identifying quandrants or numbering the hands.  Currently I am using a bit approach and identifying the hands in a clockwise fashion starting from "noon" (or straight up).  I use a 0 for no hand in that location and a 1 to indicate there is a hand.
[image: All hands on deck]

I've created the charts below to represent the available connections and those that would not connect.  I hope it's obvious that in lines 3 and 4 of the chart those clocks that have a connection would be aligned to the left of the "origin" clock.

[image: Rows 1 and 2]

[image: Rows 3 and 4]

To read the chart, take the first row as an example.  The origin clock will connect to the two clocks under "has connection" (if each were immediately aligned to the right of the origin).  The "no connection" clock has no possible connection regardless of whether it were aligned to the right or the left of the origin.

The numbers are my current attempt to apply a pattern but may be a red herring in that they don't really seem to be providing me any help to devise an algorithm.  Use or ignore them as you see fit.

All this said, I'm open to using any sort of technique including graphic collisions or any pre-built library that might make this easier.  I even quickly looked into directed graphs and vector collisions but it seemed to rapidly evolve into overkill.

FWIW, I'm using Javascript for the solution.

Comment: Seems interesting let's read it. But hey is it fair if we try to help you? So you can win the challenge?

Comment: This isn't a published challenge or anything so no worries about help.  It's more a pet project that I'm working on in my spare time to do something besides the constant enterprise programming to which I'm subjected.

Comment: your image makes some sense, but IMHO it also shows one of your problems: you can't have an image like this and say "lines 3,4 are kind of the other way around", go and draw something else, that is enough sophisticated to make those differences. Otherwise you won't be able to draw conclusions on how to write code by looking at a partially wrong image

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've modified the chart to break it into a "right" and "left" version

Comment: I think we need to chat comments and comments so we can solve it. Are you here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var clock1 = 6; // 0110
var clock2 = 3; // 0011
var direction = 4;
  // 8 = clock2 is above clock1
  // 4 = clock2 is to the right of clock1
  // 2 = clock2 is below clock1
  // 1 = clock2 is to the left of clock1
var connected = (clock2 * 4 % 15 & clock1 & direction) != 0;
```

Comment: This looks promising and inventive.  I'll do some checks.  Thanks!

Comment: Finally had some time and wrote a script to randomize inputs and check the code above.  Worked great!  Thanks!

Comment: Care to expand on this and share your thought process a bit?  I figured it out in hindsight but I'm not certain I would have come to this solution initially.  Very nice.

Comment: `clock * 4 % 15` is the same as 180° rotation :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say a row of clocks looks like this:

```
var row = [
    [0,1,1,0],
    [0,0,1,1],
    [1,0,0,1],
    [1,1,0,0],
];
```

You only care about the "3" and "9" position when comparing side-by-side. For any given pair, you care about the "3" position on the left, and the "9" position on the right, so:

```
for (var i=1;i<row.length;i++) {
    var clock_left = row[i-1];
    var clock_right = row[i];
    var they_touch = clock_left[1] * clock_right[3];
}
```

They variable `they_touch` will be 1 if the hands touch, otherwise 0.

To do columns, arrange your clocks into `columns` instead of rows, and compare the "12" and "6" positions.

Comment: I think this looks good but I had considered and discounted it.  Now i can't for the life of me remember why.  I'll check it out again and do some more prototyping.  Thanks.